# OpenVPN connection limited

Tags: vpn, openvpn

Just successfully installed (after 2 days trying!) my openvpn today. But it seems the bandwidth is limited because when I use ssh tunnel I can reach 300++ KB/s with no problem compared to using openvpn which cannot pass the 170KB/s maximum.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using `proto udp` on both ends?  `proto tcp` will be slower.

See if `comp-lzo` makes a difference.

Comment: I'm using proto tcp. I see comp-lzo on my client config should I remove it?

Comment: Leave comp-lzo and use udp instead.  With proto tcp, you are doing a bad thing called "tcp within tcp" which can hurt performance.

Comment: http://sites.inka.de/~W1011/devel/tcp-tcp.html